# How to select highest common value across groups

Tags: sql-server, linq

`Suppose I have a set of data with 2 fields - Type and Date. I am interested in finding (if exists) the the max common date across the various types. Is this easier to do in SQL or LINQ?

Given the data below the result should be `2018-02-01` as this is the max common date for all types. It there is no such date then no data is returned.

```
Type, Date
---------
1,2018-03-01
1,2018-02-01
1,2018-01-01

2,2018-02-01
2,2018-05-01
2,2018-01-01

3,2018-01-01
3,2018-03-01
3,2018-02-01
```

Comment: You have answers - but be careful about the assumption you built into your sample data. Is it possible that a given type has multiple rows with the same date?

Comment: And consider what happens with all the answers when there is no common date among all the type values.

Comment: SMor - thanks for pointing this out - For my actual case, there will not be a case with duplicate date in the same type. I think the answer from Lamu handles either case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll work if you have an unlimited or indeterminable number of Types:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample ([Type] int, [DAte] date);
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
(1,'20180301'),
(1,'20180201'),
(1,'20180101'),
(2,'20180201'),
(2,'20180501'),
(2,'20180101'),
(3,'20180101'),
(3,'20180301'),
(3,'20180201');
GO

WITH EntryCount AS(
    SELECT [Type], [Date],
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION By [Date]) AS Entries
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT MAX(Date)
FROM EntryCount EC
WHERE Ec.Entries = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sq.[Type]) FROM #Sample sq);
GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Not sure how quick it'll be either though.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Date], COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Date) AS cnt
FROM tab
ORDER BY cnt DESC, [Date] DESC
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7fd6288c89efe2655bce6534d928cf4a)**

Comment: Although the OP has marked marked this as the answer, I do wonder if this works as intended if a no date is shared by all the types. If they don't want a result returned in that scenario, then this would give a false positive. If they then want the most common date (so all but one type for example), then this works as intended.

Comment: @Larnu - you are right to point this out. Thanks. My intention was to get an empty result if there were no common date across types.

Comment: @Anand then, no offence to the answer provided by lad2025, you'll need to use the solution supplied by either myself or Sean Lange. This answer and John Cappelletti's will provide a dataset when no date is shared across all dates; just the most common maximum date.

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
Select Top 1 [Date]
 from  YourTable
 Group By [Date]
 Order By count([Type]) desc,[Date] desc
```

**Returns**

```
2018-02-01
```

Comment: I tried to select your answer as correct too - with the one from lad2025 but I am able to mark only 1 as correct. Thanks so much for responding!

Comment: @Anand No worries  :)  You pick the answer you like best.   That is the beauty of SO, you get options.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be very efficient not matter how you slice it because you have to compare across three groups. Assuming you have 3 types you could use a self join. Something like this.

```
select MAX(YourDate)
from YourTable yt
join YourTable yt2 on yt2.YourType = 2 and yt.YourDate = yt2.YourDate
join YourTable yt3 on yt3.YourType = 3 and yt.YourDate = yt3.YourDate
where yt.YourType = 1
```